# Como adjuntar una imagen a un correo, utilizando la libreria smtplib de python

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp

Que debería modificar/añadir para que este trozo de código pueda mandar imagénes adjuntas.

```
def send_email(usuario,paswor,correo):

  try:
    server=smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com:587")
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(config.EMAIL_ADDRES,config.PASSWORD)
    server.sendmail(config.EMAIL_ADDRES,correo)
    server.quit()
    print("E-Mail enviado con éxito")

except:
    print("ERROR AL ENVIAR EL MENSAGE")
```

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Aquí le tengo un código para poder enviar imagen a un correo por esa librería en Python. Colocaré el código completo para que revises y compares:

```
# Importamos librerías
import smtplib
import mimetypes

# Importamos los módulos necesarios
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage
from email.Encoders import encode_base64

# Creamos objeto Multipart, quien será el recipiente que enviaremos
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From']="desde@gmail.com"
msg['To']="hasta@alu.uct.cl"
msg['Subject']="Correo con imagen Adjunta"

# Adjuntamos Imagen
file = open("fondo.jpg", "rb")
attach_image = MIMEImage(file.read())
attach_image.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename = "avatar.png"')
msg.attach(attach_image)

# Autenticamos
mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.starttls()
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.login("desde@gmail.com","pasword")

# Enviamos
mailServer.sendmail("desde@gmail.com", "hasta@alu.uct.cl", msg.as_string())

# Cerramos conexión
mailServer.close()
```